# How to force Laravel Eloquent to play nicely with a query which returns no results?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, laravel, eloquent

I have a database query set up as a scoped query in one of my models, where in some instances no results may be returned, and it's perfectly fine for it to do so:

```
public function scopeLastFromLaunchSite($query, $site) {
    return $query->whereComplete()->whereHas('launchSite', function($q) use($site) {
        $q->where('name',$site);
    })->orderBy('launch_order_id','DESC')->first();
}
```

This function is simply called via:

```
Mission::LastFromLaunchSite('someSite');
```

This query works **perfectly fine** if there is at least one row in the result, but as soon as there is none, it returns a hugely lengthy Builder object that is filled with recursions which essentially crashes my browser.

#### My question is...

How can I detect this and simply return something like `false` or `"No results were found."`?

#### What I've tried...

I've tried using the `firstOrFail()` method in place of `first()`, but that simply returns a `ModelNotFoundException` which gives me two solutions:

1. Handle it in `global.php` with `App:error`. This is not preferable as no returned results is not an error. Just one of the many possible outcomes.
2. Catch the exception in each method, which results in code duplication. I've actually been unable to get this to work either. I try `using` the `ModelNotFoundException` class and catching it, but it never gets caught:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

   // ...

   try {
       //my query
   } catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
       return false;
   }

   // otherwise, return as normal
   ```

How can I simply return `false` or some falsey value when a query on my model returns no results, instead of simply printing out this hugely lengthy error?

Comment: how do u call this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using scopes like Laravel intends you do. Laravel actually don't expects that you actually execute the query inside a scope. It's rather a tool to apply filters. So when your scope function returns `NULL` (or any falsy value) Laravel will just return the current Builder object anyways:

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

```
protected function callScope($scope, $parameters)
{
    array_unshift($parameters, $this);

    return call_user_func_array(array($this->model, $scope), $parameters) ?: $this;
}
```

Here are three solutions:

#### 1. Use the exception (but in your controller)

I don't like this very much, but it is a possibility. Use `firstOrFail` and do this in your controller:

```
try {
    $result = Mission::LastFromLaunchSite('someSite');
} catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e){
    $result = null;
}
```

#### 2. Use the scope right

Don't execute the query in the scope but instead in your controller:

```
public function scopeLastFromLaunchSite($query, $site) {
    return $query->whereComplete()->whereHas('launchSite', function($q) use($site) {
        $q->where('name',$site);
    })->orderBy('launch_order_id','DESC');
}
```

Usage:

```
Mission::LastFromLaunchSite('someSite')->first();
```

#### 3. Just add a normal function to your model that does the same

```
public static function LastFromLaunchSite($site){
    return $query->whereComplete()->whereHas('launchSite', function($q) use($site) {
        $q->where('name',$site);
    })->orderBy('launch_order_id','DESC')->first();
}
```

Usage:

```
Mission::LastFromLaunchSite('someSite');
```

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are not supposed to return the query result, that's why you get never-ending recursion or other errors, depending on your code.

Change the scope to:

```
public function scopeLastFromLaunchSite($query, $site) {
    $query->whereComplete()->whereHas('launchSite', function($q) use($site) {
        $q->where('name',$site);
    })->orderBy('launch_order_id','DESC');
}
```

then execute it in-place:

```
$result = $yourQuery->lastFromLaunchSite($site)->first();

// then do whatever you need with the result
return ($result) ?: 'nothing found!';
```

---

Explanation: Scopes do not require return value. If the scopeWhatever`method returns anything that evaluates to`true`, then it replaces the base query, otherwise the query itself is returned. That said, if you expect single model to be returned, but there's no row matching criteria, then you get unexpectedly the query object.

You could als do this (I wouldn't, but it will work as well):

```
public function scopeLastFromLaunchSite($query, $site) {
    $row = $query->whereComplete()->whereHas('launchSite', function($q) use($site) {
        $q->where('name',$site);
       })->orderBy('launch_order_id','DESC')->first();

    return $row ?: 'nothing found!';
}
```

but then you need to expec either `Model` or `string` and adjust your code accordingly in order to avoid possible `Trying to get property of non-object` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done such thing, but what comes to my mind first would be sth. like:

```
public function scopeLastFromLaunchSite($query, $site) {
    $retVal = $query->whereComplete()->whereHas('launchSite', function($q) use($site) {
        $q->where('name', $site);
    })->orderBy('launch_order_id', 'DESC');

    if ($retVal->count() > 0) {
        return $retVal->first();
    }

    return "No results found";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call the query twice. Just check if result evaluates to `true`